# Ordering a collection by another one

Tags: java, collections

I have two `ArrayList` collections, let's call them `A` and `B`. `A`is a subset of `B` and `A` has less elements than `B` (`A` has around 10% elements `B`). However the elements in `A` are not ordered the same way they were in `B` and I need them to be.

I can come up with an algorithm that will order them as in the original collection. What I'm asking is, if there is some nice way to do it, maybe part of JDK or part of Apache Commons.

Comment: Not ordered the same way does not tell us how you want to order it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a comparator that compares the objects in the smaller list according to their index in the larger list.

There certainly are several options for implementing this.

A *very* simple but **very** inefficient one would be to create a comparator that checks the indices of the elements with `largerList.indexOf(element)`. But this would have **horrible** running time for all but the smallest lists.

A more sopisticated solution would be to store a *mapping* from the elements to their index in the larger list, so that the indices can be looked up directly. This will be *significantly* faster, at the cost of some extra storage for the `Map`.

Both approaches are implemented here as an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class SameOrderTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
        listA.add("S");
        listA.add("A");
        listA.add("M");
        listA.add("P");
        listA.add("L");
        listA.add("E");
        listA.add("W");
        listA.add("O");
        listA.add("R");
        listA.add("D");

        List<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
        listB.add("A");
        listB.add("M");
        listB.add("S");
        listB.add("E");
        listB.add("L");

        List<String> listB0 = new ArrayList<String>(listB);
        Collections.sort(listB0, simpleSameOrderComparator(listA));

        List<String> listB1 = new ArrayList<String>(listB);
        Collections.sort(listB1, efficientSameOrderComparator(listA));

        System.out.println("A : "+listA);
        System.out.println("B0: "+listB0);
        System.out.println("B1: "+listB1);
    }

    // WARNING: Simple but VERY inefficient
    private static <T> Comparator<T> simpleSameOrderComparator(
        final List<T> reference)
    {
        return new Comparator<T>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(T t0, T t1)
            {
                return reference.indexOf(t0)-reference.indexOf(t1);
            }
        };
    }

    private static <T> Comparator<T> efficientSameOrderComparator(
        final List<T> reference)
    {
        final Map<T, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<T, Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i<reference.size(); i++)
        {
            map.put(reference.get(i), i);
        }
        return new Comparator<T>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(T t0, T t1)
            {
                return map.get(t0)-map.get(t1);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

I'm curious whether there is a solution that does not affect the running time of the sort algorithm and does *not* need extra storage. If the size of the smaller list is only 10%, one could possibly reverse the lookup and only store the indices of the elements that actually are contained in the smaller list, but in this case, the running time will depend on the sizes of the lists and the ratio of the sizes, and it's hard to tell beforehand whether this will pay off.

---

EDIT: Inspired by the [answer of Eugene Kuleshov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25793968/3182664) (+1), I created a test that uses his approach, but with a set instead of a list: It should have a running time of O(m+n) where `m` and `n` are the sizes of the lists.

(EDIT2: updated based on the comments)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class SameOrderTest2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
        listA.add("S");
        listA.add("A");
        listA.add("M");
        listA.add("P");
        listA.add("L");
        listA.add("E");
        listA.add("W");
        listA.add("O");
        listA.add("R");
        listA.add("D");

        List<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
        listB.add("A");
        listB.add("M");
        listB.add("S");
        listB.add("E");
        listB.add("L");

        List<String> listB0 = sorted(listA, listB);
        System.out.println("A : "+listA);
        System.out.println("B0: "+listB0);
    }

    private static <T> List<T> sorted(List<T> reference, List<T> toSort)
    {
        List<T> referenceList = new ArrayList<T>(reference);
        referenceList.retainAll(new LinkedHashSet<T>(toSort));
        return referenceList;
    }


}
```

This also requires additional storage, but is very concise and elegant, **if** you may create a new instance for the second list, and don't have to sort it in-place.

Comment: It does NOT make sense to use a Set for collection that is being iterated trough, such as your referenceSet during retainAll() call. Also, it's unlikely you'll benefit from such micro-optimizations in a real map. In my experience, on a modern hardware, collections where it starts to pay off are over several hundred elements. Oh, and OP asked for a standard library, not a custom Comparator. :)

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov  Well, I think it does make sense to first convert the reference collection into a collection that has O(1) for removal of elements. It could also be a `LinkedList`, or some other collection - but an `ArrayList`, for example, has O(n) for the `remove` operation...

Comment: Marco13, ArrayList.retailAll() is not using a regular remove(). Look at the source code.

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov Yes, and `remove(object)` has O(n) on an `ArrayList`. You're right with saying that there are many cases where such theoretical (asymptotical) considerations are not important, but if the lists contain a few thousand elements, this might become relevant.

Comment: @Marco13 once gain, remove() method is not called from within ArrayList.retainAll(), so you are driving your conclusions from the wrong assumptions

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov You're right for `ArrayList`: `retainAll` is overridden in `ArrayList`. This must not be the case for all lists, however....

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov I just noticed that indeed some of my previous comments did not make sense: The reference has to be copied anyhow, and it can be copied into a list or a set. But the type of the list can be choosen in the method, so there are no assumptions necessary about the type of the *input* list. (And, at least for me, surprisingly, it's even faster when the larger collection is copied into a list and not into a set - updated the answer accordingly)

Comment: And that, my friend, you should not micro-optimize without actual performance-testing. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can copy your bigger collection and then call `retainAll()` method to remove missing elements, preserving the order:

```
ArrayList result = new ArrayList(B).retainAll(A);
```

Effectively it will call `contains()` on your collection A, so for big collections, a `Set` would perform better than and `ArrayList`.

Comment: Yes, this has quadratic running time in the size of the smaller list, but I liked the idea and just created a test based on this (+1), I'll edit my answer.